# Show that the empty set is independent of $A$ for any $A$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am somewhat stumped as to how to approach this. The only thing I can remotely think of is $$P(A\cap \emptyset) = P(\emptyset)$$ but nothing else comes to mind. Suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Events $A$ and $B$ are independent precisely when the following statement is true:
$$P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$$
([Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_%28probability_theory%29#Two_events)). In your situation, $B=\varnothing$. You are correct that $A\cap\varnothing=\varnothing$ for any $A$, and that therefore $P(A\cap\varnothing)=P(\varnothing)$ for any $A$. Thus, to check whether any event $A$ is independent from $\varnothing$, you need to check whether for any $A$, the following statement is true:
$$P(\varnothing)=P(A)P(\varnothing)$$
Do you know what $P(\varnothing)$ is?

Comment: Only thing that comes to mind is $p(\emptyset) = 0$ so then $ 0 = p(A)0$

Comment: That's all there is to it. You're overthinking this ;)

Comment: Story of my existence in higher level mathematics, when to actually just accept the definitions how they're provided and use them, instead i always do the latter.....